# What is Nano Zinc Oxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, materials, nanotechnology

First of all, I have zero chemical background, but I seek for an easy explanation about Nano Zinc Oxide.

I was told that the name of "Nano Zinc Oxide" couldn't possibly exist. Instead, it should be coined as "Nano Zinc Chelate", since an Oxide particle is quite big and Nano is so small, relatively. It sounds very contradictory.

I know there is, of course, Nano Zinc Oxide, but I don't understand what he really means and  I feel enthusiastic to understand it.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

Nano Zinc Oxide ($\ce{ZnO}$) is a nanomaterial and a nanomaterial is described as

> materials of which a single unit
>   is sized (in at least one dimension) between 1 and 1000 nanometers
>   ($10^{-9} m$) but is usually between 1—100 nm

Nano zinc oxide  can be synthesized using different approaches that included's both chemical (precipitation, reduction etc) and physical (depositon) methods . You can read more about nano zinc oxide and its application in this paper [Journal of Physics: Condensed Matter Volume 16 Number 25](http://iopscience.iop.org/0953-8984/16/25/R01/pdf/0953-8984_16_25_R01.pdf)

[image]

This is an image of Nano Zinc oxide grown as a flower (nano-flower) for [sensor applications](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn10001-nanoflowers-show-promise-for-alcohol-detection.html)

Answer (score 2):

Nano zinc oxide is a real material used in sunscreens and looks like [this](https://www.flickr.com/photos/fei_company/4790479142/).  It is just little crystals of zinc oxide which are about 30 nm across.

Chelate refers to something which is produced by a chemical process of [chelation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelation).  Chelation means that a metal atom has more than one chemical bond to surrounding organics.  (That is kind of a bad definition, but I'm trying to keep the lingo simple.)  Chelation can be [used to produce zinc oxide](https://www.infona.pl/resource/bwmeta1.element.elsevier-3dbd34bb-146e-39d1-be89-b6f4cce12c61), but I don't think this is the process used for manufacturing most industrial zinc oxide.

Comment: He is still questioning a lot more which is beyond my ability to understand. At least, I understand its general concept. Thank you again.